# cx_Oracle query returns zero rows

Tags: python, sql, cx-oracle

Why does the below code not work ? It returns zero rows even though I have many multiple matching  the search criteria.

A simple query of the form `select * from Table_1` works fine and returns positive number of rows

```
import cx_Oracle
def function_A (data):
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect('omitted details here')

    for index in range(len(data)):
        # connection is already open
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        query = "select * from Table_1 where column_1=:column1 and column_2=:column2 and column_3=:column3 and column_4=:column4"
        bindVars={'column1':data[index][3], 'column2':data[index][4], 'column4':data[index][5], 'column5':data[index][6]}
        cursor.execute(query, bindVars)
        cursor.arraysize = 256
        rowCount = 0
        resultSet = cursor.fetchall()
        if (resultSet != None):
            logger.debug("Obtained a resultSet with length = %s", len(resultSet))
            for index in range(len(resultSet)):
                logger.debug("Fetched one row from cursor, incrementing counter !!")
                rowCount = rowCount + 1
                logger.debug("Fetched one row from cursor, incremented counter !!")
            logger.debug("Successfully executed the select statement for table Table_1; that returned %s rows !!", rowCount)
            logger.debug("Successfully executed the select statement for table Table_1; that returned %s rows !!", cursor.rowcount)
```

Please ignore minor formatting issues, code runs just does not give me a positive number of rows.

Code is being run on IBM AIX with python2.6 and a compatible version of cx_Oracle.

Answer (score 5):

Oracle CX's [cursor](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cursor.html) object has a read-only `rowcount` property. `Rowcount` is returning how many rows are returned with fetch* methods.

Say the query yields 5 rows, then the interaction is like this

1. execute   rowcount = 0
2. fetchone  rowcount = 1
3. fetchone  rowcount = 2
4. fetchall  rowcount = 5

Thay way you do not need to manually track it. Your query issues will have to be resolved first offcourse :)

Comment: While this answer is correct wrt how Oracle CX's cursor behaves, it's worth pointing out that [this behaviour is wrong and not as per the spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rowcount). In fact, how Oracle's cx `.rowcount` behaves for `SELECT`'s is exactly what [`.rownumber`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rownumber) is supposed to do: _"This read-only attribute should provide the current 0-based index of the cursor in the result set or `None` if the index cannot be determined."_ And of course, `'cx_Oracle.Cursor' object has no attribute 'rownumber'`.

Comment: @aneroid Thanks for a great comment!

Answer (score 1):

Your query returns 0 rows because there are 0 rows that match your query. Either remove a predicate from your WHERE clause or change the value you pass into one.

It's worth noting that you're not binding anything to `column3` in your `bindVars` variable. I'm also not entirely certain why you're iterating, `cursor.rowcount`, as you have it gives you the number of rows that have been fetched by the cursor.

Generally, if you think a SELECT statement is not returning the correct result then take it our of code and run it directly against the database. Bind all variables first so you can see *exactly* what you're actually running.

Comment: Also, `column5` is not listed in the query but its in `bindVars`.

Comment: I don't think that would make a difference @Burhan; removing a predicate won't restrict the number of rows being returned.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would trigger an error or not, but its another thing (among many) that should be fixed with the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

banging my head against monitor on this one... you have to do something like below to check, as the cursor value changes once you operate on it:

```
    result_set = DB_connector.execute(sql)
    result_list = result_set.fetchall()  # assign the return row to a list
    if result_set.rowcount == 0:
        print('DB check failed, no row returned')
        sql_result_set = None
    else:
        for row in result_list:  # use this instead result_set 
            print('row fetched: ' + row[0])
            sql_result_set.append(row[0])
            print('DB test Passed')
```